# MVC @Html.ActionLink with Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditProg", new { id = item.ID })
```

I like to know how to also supply the above with a name as I need trap this name before it is submitted. Is there something like `name = "EditLink"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like adding a `name` attribute to the anchor (even if this attribute is not valid on an anchor)?

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Edit",                        // linkText
    "EditProg",                    // actionName
    new { id = item.ID },          // routeValues
    new { name = "EditLink" }      // htmlAttributes
)
```

or sending it to the controller as query string parameter?

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Edit",                 // linkName
    "EditProg",             // actionName
    new {                   // routeValues
        id = item.ID, 
        name = "some name" 
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could used Url.Action instead?

`<a href="@Url.Action("EditProg")" id="@item.ID" name="editlink" >`

Comment: Why using something like this when there's already an ActionLink overload which allows to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("EditLink","Edit", "EditProg", new { id = item.EmpID })
```

Comment: Hi @vaibhav-parab, welcome to the community. I'm reviewing your answer and I noticed some potential improvements. 1) Please use the correct markdown for the code segments (see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) and 2) provide some additional commentary on what exactly your answer does/change in relation to question. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).